# Should I repeat “the” by enumeration?

Tags: definite-articles

Should I repeat the by enumeration different theatres?

*He has worked with many Moscow theatres, among them there are the Russian Academic Youth, the Maly, the Yermolova, the Oleg Tabakov, the Russian Army, the Pushkin and the Mossoviet theatres and the Moscow Operetta.*

By the way, should I also repeat the word *theatres* in the end as I do in the example?

Comment: I would reword your sentence as follows: He has worked with many Moscow theatres, among them the Moscow Operetta and the Russian Academic Youth, Maly, Yermolova, Oleg Tabakov, Russian Army, Pushkin, and Mossoviet. (Your original sentence is actually a run-on sentence.) See this related post: When should I repeat the definite article? http://english.stackexchange.com/q/144001/18655

Answer (score 1):

You should only repeat 'the', or 'theatre', where they are part of the name.

In Toronto we have theatres called "The Factory Theatre", "Buddies in Bad Times" and "Soulpepper Theatre". If you wished to list them you would say:

> Theatres I have worked with include: Buddies in Bad Times, The Factory Theatre, and Soulpepper Theatre.

You could shorten the names if it was clear what you meant (e.g. "I have worked with Buddies in Bad Times, Factory, and Soulpepper.") but you shouldn't add to the names.